# How to conveniently add a large set of regressors in R?

Tags: r, regression

I have to add approximately 30 dummy variables to a regression.

If my variables would be named `dummy1` - `dummy30`, I would denote this with an asterisk wildcard in  `STATA`. It would be simply `regress y dummy*` and `STATA` would add all variables starting with 'dummy'.

Can anyone hint me to a similar convenient procedure in `[R]` which prevents me from writing out 30 variable names?

Comment: `y ~ ., data = <a data.frame with only the columns you want to include in your regression, where you can use a regular expression for subsetting>`

Comment: Thanks, but what if I would like it to more flexible? That is, I know a K amount of dummy variables in my data frame but they are scattered. I would have to specify the exact column numbers which is undesirable.

Comment: If you dummies encode a factor variable, you should be aware that R regression functions can do that for you.

Comment: You can subset using regular expressions any variable you want (and then use the `y ~ .` formula).

Comment: That's a good point, @Roland, letting R include my variable as a factor. If I remember correctly: `as.factor()`.

Answer (score 4):

You have two options. Either subset a `data.frame` to contain only dummy* variables and the dependent variable. In which case, you can call `lm(dep ~ ., data = your.data)`. The dot argument will assume you're trying to use all but `dep` as predictors.
To subset a `data.frame` of only `dep` and predictors, you can use `your.data[grepl("dep|dummy", names(your.data)), ]`.

Second option is to construct a formula argument using paste.

```
formula(paste("dep ~", paste("dummy", 1:10, sep = "", collapse = "+")))
```

Answer (score 3):

The function `reformulate` is the right option for creating formulas based on strings.

An example data frame:

```
set.seed(1)
dat <- data.frame(y = rnorm(10), 
                  dummy1 = rnorm(10),
                  dummy2 = rnorm(10),
                  dummy3 = rnorm(10),
                  other = rnorm(10))
```

Now, `grep` is used to find all `dummy*` variables. The result is used for the function `reformulate`:

```
form <- reformulate(grep("^dummy", names(dat), value = TRUE), response = "y")
# y ~ dummy1 + dummy2 + dummy3
```

This formula can be used for `lm`:

```
lm(form, dat)
# Call:
#   lm(formula = form, data = dat)
# 
# Coefficients:
#   (Intercept)       dummy1       dummy2       dummy3  
# 0.04785      0.09323     -0.63404     -0.19547
```